# Why does my React App.js gets render 3 times only on page refresh?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, oauth, react-router-dom

I am not sure why the return statements within App.js gets called 3 times during page refreshes.

My Index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import "assets/plugins/nucleo/css/nucleo.css";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
import "assets/scss/argon-dashboard-react.scss";

import { Auth0ProviderWithNavigate } from "./auth0-provider-with-navigate";
import { App } from "./app";
import store from "./app/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Auth0ProviderWithNavigate>
      <Provider store={store}>
        {console.log("Hit from Index")}
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </Auth0ProviderWithNavigate>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

My App.js

```
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthenticationGuard } from "./components/authentication-guard";
import Admin from "layouts/Admin.js";
import Auth from "layouts/Auth.js";

export const App = () => {
  const { isLoading } = useAuth0();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Hit from App UseEffect");
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {console.log("Hit from App Return", isLoading)}{" "}
      {isLoading ? (
        <div className="page-layout">
          <Auth />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Auth />} exact />
          <Route path="/auth/*" element={<Auth />} />
          <Route
            path="/admin/*"
            element={<AuthenticationGuard component={Admin} />}
          />
        </Routes>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

[console.log results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlWaN.png)

When I first load the page via login the return statements within App.js gets called 2 times (expected) however if I were to refresh the page it gets called 3 times whereas I expected 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have some confusion about what your logs mean. You are console logging as an unintentional side-effect in the `App` component's return statement, so any "expected behavior" should be thrown out the window. React can "render" your component, e.g. call the function, as many times as it needs to in order to compute what needs to be committed to the DOM.

Always use the `useEffect` hook to log data so you have a one-to-one relation between render (***to the DOM***) and an effect.

```
export const App = () => {
  const { isLoading } = useAuth0();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Mounting App useEffect");
  }, []); // <-- run once when component mounted/initial render

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Render App to the DOM useEffect");
  }); // <-- no dependency, run once each render

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect because isLoading updated", isLoading);
  }, [isLoading]); // <-- run only when isLoading updates

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <div className="page-layout">
          <Auth />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Auth />} exact />
          <Route path="/auth/*" element={<Auth />} />
          <Route
            path="/admin/*"
            element={<AuthenticationGuard component={Admin} />}
          />
        </Routes>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Using your code, "Render App to the DOM useEffect" gets logged 3 times for page refreshes, but only 2 times for normal page visits. I am confuse as to why it is 3 renders. Is it a side effect of how React works?

Comment: @Noki Possibly. Are you rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component by any chance? In non-production builds it will effect double-invocations of specific lifecycle methods/hooks/etc, and in React 18 include a double-mounting of components as a check to "ensure reusable state". This means you may see additional "effects" run, it's a development tool, and only runs in non-production builds of your app.

Comment: No React.StrictMode here

Comment: @Noki Ok, it might just be React rerendering an extra time on the initial run then. React is optimized to run/perform quite well out-of-the-box, so I wouldn't fuss too much about this. A general rule is to let React render when React thinks it needs to render. Going out of your way to prevent component renders is likely to lead to bugs. Only look to optimize renders if you have a noticeable and audited performance problem.